# Header that changes on scroll

Tags: navigation, scrolling

Is there an official name for a header who's characteristics (e.g. background color, height, etc) or that of its content change as the user scrolls?

An example can be found on [engadget.com](https://www.engadget.com) where the links collapse in to a dropdown menu as the user scrolls down the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We call this behaviour a '**responsive header**' as it changes depending on the viewport or scroll depth.

**Responsive** covers all bases when it comes to a dynamically changing asset.

But there will be a few different versions of the same name for this.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually have a name to be honest, one alias as @sclarke mentioned in the comments is *responsive header*.

People also call it:

- **dynamic** header/menu
- **interactive** header/menu
- **collapsing** header/menu

Not all things have a fixed name, only somewhat of a description of what it does.

Answer (score 1):

At one of my previous companies, it was called a "sticky nav" since it sticks to the top of the page and had links to sections on the page.